# Applescript, time of date

Tags: xml, date, time, applescript

Please excuse me if the following gets a bit messy, my first post here and also my first time trying to explain such a problem I'm having.

I have a script that's getting XML data from a curl to an open API of a transportation company. It parses the data and puts all XML elements named "Line" in an array. Then a repeat goes through every one of those elements and creates variables containing data from those XML elements.

Now, one of those XML elements contain a value of departure times in the format of dateTtime, like "2017-01-31T14:04:00". I put that value in a variable and then I want to separate the time and the date. So I use AppleScript's text item delimiters and set it to "T" and then I create a variable that I set to "text item 2" of the previous one. Works fine, I get the time data stored in the variable.

Now I want to use Applescripts "time of date" on that variable, in order to get the time in seconds. Here it breaks, I get an error message stating "System event got an error: Can not change time of date "14:04:00" of XML file "Macintosh HD:Users:John:Desktop:my_xml_file.xml" to type string".

Here is the code:

```
set theXMLFile to "/Users/John/Desktop/my_xml_file.xml"

set poster to {}

tell application "System Events"
    set xmlData to XML file theXMLFile
    tell contents of xmlData
        try
            set poster to XML elements of XML element "Lines" of XML element "GetDepartureArrivalResult" of XML element "GetDepartureArrivalResponse" of XML element "soap:Body" of XML element "soap:Envelope" whose name is "Line"
            repeat with i from 1 to (count poster)
                set departure to value of XML element "JourneyDateTime" of item i of poster as text
                set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "T"
                set depTime to text item 2 of departure
                display dialog time of date (depTime as string)
                set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
            end repeat
        on error errStr
            display dialog errStr
        end try
    end tell
end tell
```

If I modify this code in a test script to the following:

```
set departure to "2017-01-31T14:04:00" as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "T"
set depTime to text item 2 of departure
display dialog depTime
display dialog time of date (depTime as string)
```

Then I get a dialog showing the correct number of seconds and no error message.

I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong =/

Answer (score 0):

System events doesn't handle the concept of time you want. Tell "me" instead, like this:

```
            set departure to value of XML element "JourneyDateTime" of item i of poster as text
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "T"
            set depTime to text item 2 of departure
            tell me to display dialog time of date (depTime as string)
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
```

Comment: Before I read your post I managed to solve it by using:


`set depTimeSeconds to my getTimeInSeconds(depTime)`

and

`on getTimeInSeconds(myTime)
 set tempDate to date myTime
 set tempSeconds to time of tempDate
 return tempSeconds
end getTimeInSeconds`

Comment: It works because when using the handler you leave the System Events tell block. Another way of doing it is to tell "me" within the System Events tell block

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that constructing a date from a string is sensitive to the region and time format settings in System Preferences. I would guess that you have 12 hour time configured rather than 24, so you can't make a date with "14:04:00". You can make it with "02:04:00 PM" though.

Comment: No, as staget before it worked in a separate script with no referens to an xml file, just a static text. I'm also using 24h format.